# PHP incomprehensible control flow

Tags: php

I have done a few projects in PHP but I am still far from being an expert. I am now trying to debug an application written by someone else.

There is a point in the code I cannot quite understand and I am out of ideas. Here is some background information.

The code is supposed to retrieve a PDF file and render a page with the PDF file shown in
an internal `div`. For certain documents this works. For other documents, the PDF file is sent to the client (the browser download dialog opens up) and no page is displayed.

I have added lots of `fwrite` to log certain actions to a log file while the page is rendered. To my astonishment, I have the following situation:

```
fwrite($fh, "HERE3\n");

$templateMgr =& TemplateManager::getManager();

fwrite($fh, "HERE4\n");
```

When the page is rendered correctly, both lines ('HERE3' and 'HERE4') are logged.
When the page is not rendered at all and the PDF file is sent for download, only 'HERE3' is logged.

What puzzles me is how this can possibly happen: there is no **if** or **return** between the two log lines! My only explanation for the code not logging the second line is that it crashes after logging 'HERE3'. But then, I would expect either of the two:

1. The code logs both lines and continues until the end and renders the page (OK), or
2. The code logs only the first line, then crashes and DOES NOT PRODUCE ANY OUTPUT. Instead, the program sends a PDF file to the client.

I have also logged the call to getManager(), and it returns without crashing.

So, my question is, how can this code break execution after a function call, and yet produce a meaningful output?

Comment: cannot give an answer without knowing what getManager does.

Comment: @WvanRij: But can a subroutine just skip the rest of the script and still produce a response? Anyway, getManager() first tries to retrieve an object from a registry and, if it does not find it, it creates a new one. The constructor is pretty complex and I am still trying to understand it. But still, how can a subroutine skip the rest of the script and still produce output?

Comment: @Giorgio any place in a php script can can call `die;` or `exit;` and the execution will stop at that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whats is the code behind `Template::getManager` ?
You probably have an `exit;` somewhere in your code.

It's a common usage to call an `exit;` after sending an http download output with `header()`, knowing that this fonction does not stop the script whereas it has a redirection behavior. Usually you don't need the rest to be executed. So be sure to check for exit function ;)

Comment: Thanks, this seems a reasonable thing to look for. I really haven't touched PHP for many years.

Comment: It is a bit more complex than a plain exit() but you gave me the correct hint. +1 and accepted.

Comment: After more debugging I discovered that the header is already sent before 'HERE3' is executed. Then the `getManager()` detects this (or some equivalent condition), and decides to exit. I have not found the exact point yet, but this allowed me to trace back the root cause of the bug by looking at the code that sends the header.